Active Storage Disk storage o production
I deployed an Rails 7.1. app on Heroku and I'm learning to work with images.
I still use the default setup for Active Storage (local - disk storage) for production, but when I'm searching files inside app/storage on Heroku I cannot find anything.
Where should these images be saved?

Using disk storage is not a viable option on Heroku as it has an ephemeral file storage system. Every time the app is restared the images will be wiped.  See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku

@max thanks for this, but I don't understand why I can't see the folders created for each image in /storage directory. I just want to understand why I can't see them, and what can I do to see them.

Dude, don't waste your time on trying to fix something that will never work out. Life is too short for that. Get a free tier Amazon S3 and spend your time on something productive.

Ok thanks, I just did this.
